# I've been to/in London for three years

Tags: sentence-construction

I usually get to see :

> I have been **to** London.

But, what if I say:

> I have been **in** London.

Do they carry the same meaning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, they do not mean the same.

- > *I have been **to** London.*

  Means that you are talking about trips or journeys specifically to London.
- > *I have been **in** London.*

  Means that that you are talking about a stay in London (which may be short, or very long, or simply passing through). It doesn't matter whether you took a trip there or not.

Answer (score 1):

*I have been **in** London for 3 years* (as in the title) means that after spending the said time in London you are still there, while the first sentence (*I have been **to** London*) means you have an *experience* of visiting London (you are not there now).